# Cannot complete the installation of android ddms for eclipse

Tags: android

i am basically at the very last step where i have installed the eclipse and went to install the new software the ADT to get the android project on the screen and i get this message

say operation cannot be completed. see details

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. 
Software being installed: Android DDMS 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762) 
Missing requirement: Android DDMS 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found

it has been almost a full week of me trying to install this program someone please ease this frustration

Comment: Try to use the latest version of eclipse(Indigo), and also the latest version of sdk

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse if you cannot access the `Android SDK` manager I suggest you unistall eclipse and restart.

On the other hand if you can access the `SDK` manager then you will be wanting to install most if not all of the software development kit environments for eclipse.

Upon install you have to start a new AVD choose your preferred SDK for that AVD and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try the latest Eclipse 3.7.2 ([Download Link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-372/indigosr2))?

What is the version of Eclipse are you using?

It is recommended on the SDK page to use the classic version, seems like you are using a different one.

Sudhaker

Answer (score 0):

Goto --> Eclipse Help --> Check for Updates  --> Update Eclipse IDE Package which will show up in the list of available updates. Restart Eclipse and now try to install ADT plugin which includes the DDMS. It should work.